# how to pass an variable of an expression to curve() as its equation?

Tags: r

I've the following code:

```
e <- expression(x^2+3*x-3)
```

I want to draw the plot of the first derivative using R's symbolic derivate function D:

```
curve(D(e), from=0, to=10)
```

But then I get the following error:

```
Error in curve(expression(e), xname = "x", from = 0, to = 3000) : 
     'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'
```

I tried to wrap D(e) in a call to eval(), but to no avail.

Trying a bit more:

```
substitute(expression(x^2+3*x-3), list(x=3))
```

results, as expected, in:

```
 expression(3^2+3*3-3)
```

But:

```
 substitute(e, list(x=3))
```

results in:

```
 e
```

What is happening? How can I get this working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a little clunky, but

```
eval(substitute(curve(y),list(y=D(e,"x"))))
```

seems to work.  So does

```
do.call(curve,list(D(e,"x")))
```

Comment: Or, equivalently, `eval(call("curve", D(e, "x"), from=0, to=1)` which uses syntax that might(?) be more human-parseable.

Comment: Aha, now I understand the behaviour of substitute and expression better. And I like the first solution of @Ben Bolker best because in that form it is easier to write, at least conceptually,: `eval(substitute(curve(y, from=0, to=10), list(y=D(e,"x"))))`

Comment: @Ben Bolker: I'm happy with a working solution, but I still doesn't really understand it.  `curve()` issues an error message explicitly say that the first argument must be an expression and `e` is a variable containing an expression, containing an `x` at that.
How is R seeing a variable containing an expression? It appears to me that R treats passed parameters different in some way.

Answer (score 4):

functions are simpler to manipulate and test:

```
e <- expression(x^2+3*x-3)
de <- D(e, 'x')
fde <- function(x) eval(de)

curve(fde, from=0, to=10)
```